# How do I select all dates that are most recent in comparison with a different date field?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to gather all dates between 06-01-2020 and 06-30-2020 based on the forecast date which can be 06-08-2020, 06-20-2020, and 06-24-2020. The problem I am running into is that I'm only grabbing all of the dates associated with the forecast date 06-24-2020. I need all dates that are most recent so if say 06-03-2020 occurs with the forecast date 06-08-2020 and not with 06-20-2020, I still need all of the dates associated with that forecast date. Here's the code I am currently using.

```
df = df[df['Forecast Date'].isin([max(df['Forecast Date'])])]
```

It's producing this-

```
            Date  \
5668  2020-06-25  
5669  2020-06-26   
5670  2020-06-27  
5671  2020-06-28  
5672  2020-06-29  
5673  2020-06-30  

     Media Granularity Forecast Date
5668               NaN    2020-06-24
5669               NaN    2020-06-24
5670               NaN    2020-06-24
5671               NaN    2020-06-24
5672               NaN    2020-06-24
5673               NaN    2020-06-24
```

With a length of 6 (`len(df[df['Forecast Date'].isin([max(df['Forecast Date'])])])`). It needs to be a length of 30, one for each unique date. It is only grabbing the columns where the max of Forecast date is 06-24-2020.

I'm thinking it's something along the lines of `df.sort_values(df[['Date', 'Forecast Date']]).drop_duplicates(df['Date'], keep='last')` but it's giving me a `key error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy but not what I expected.

`df = df.sort_values(by=['Date', 'Forecast Date']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Date'], keep='last')`